# Duplicate sub-category slugs in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

So I've run into a bit of an issue with the way I need to structure a particular site using WordPress. Take the following set of URL's for example:

- http://url.com/products/product-name/downloads/
- http://url.com/products/product-name/faq/
- http://url.com/products/product-name/release-notes/

The issue I'm running into is that wordpress will not allow me to duplicate the sub categories downloads, faq and release-notes.

Is there a plugin out there anyone is aware of that will allow duplicate category slugs as long as the category is assigned to a parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you *want* to do this. First off, it looks like your permalink structure is set up using %category%/%postname% - which in and of itself is not a good thing. Not so bad on smaller sites, but the bigger your site is, the more unnecessary strain you're putting on the server. (see "Category in Permalinks Considered Harmful" http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/)  To try and create multiple slugs would exacerbate the problem, I would think.

A way around it would possibly be to create a set of Pages for your sections (i.e. "Product Name 1", "Product Name 2", etc.) and have categories set up that are called "Release notes", "FAQ", etc.; and tag your posts with the product name.  Then you can run a query in the template file to pull in the posts that are tagged with the product page name you're currently on.  Then you'd have the permalink setup you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion in the second part. The first part however, you're completely missing the point. I'm not worried in the slightest about the most efficient way to execute my code. The computer I optimize for the human brain. In this day of cheap and affordable technology, there's just no excuse for something as simple and important as URI structure to be dictated by my software and hardware limitations. That kind of thinking is just silly.

Comment: You're not worried in the slightest about efficient code? Wow. Okay. I think that's the most interesting thing I've ever heard from someone who wants programming advice.  By the way, did you even *try* my advice? Or just discount it because it's not exactly what you think the program should be written like? I appreciate the downvote just because I'm trying to help you improve something based on the software you choose to use.  That's just wonderful.

Comment: Just for anyone coming in to this late, the url issue was resolved in Wordpress 3.3 and thus is no longer an issue.